# Iterating through vector of abstract classes

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract-class, overriding, pure-virtual

There is already a similar question, but it did not answer my question so I'll ask again.

I have this classes:

```
#ifndef _OBJECTS_H
#define _OBJECTS_H

#include "ray.h"
#include <cmath>

class Object {
    public:
        Vector3 position, color;
        Object(Vector3 position, Vector3 color): position(position), color(color){};

        virtual bool intersects() = 0;
};

class Sphere : public Object {
    public:
        float radius;
        Sphere(Vector3 center, float radius, Vector3 color): Object(center, color), radius(radius){};

        using Object::intersects;
        bool intersects(const Ray& ray, float& t);
};

#endif
```

and I need to have `std::vector` of objects and iterate through it:

```
for(Object s:objects) {
                float t;
                if (s.intersects(ray, t)) {
                    //do something
                }
            }
```

When I declare `intersects()` as `pure virtual`, then it tells me that I can't iterate through virtual class, if I declare it only as `virtual` then it tells me intersects is not implemented. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can't have `std::vector<Object>` in the first place...

Comment: `_OBJECTS_H` is a reserved identifier. By defining it, your program will have undefined behaviour.

Comment: @user2079303 Could you provide the source for this claim? Thank you.

Comment: @KillzoneKid -- "Each name that contains a double underscore _ _ or begins with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter (2.12) is reserved to the implementation for any use." [global.names]/1.

Comment: @PeteBecker Thank you. The way it was worded gave impression that _OBJECTS_H is an existing global identifier not because it starts with _O. For the use of double underscore there is some ambiguity however. I've seen quotes from standard that imply that only `__` at the beginning is reserved, while the quote you posted suggests that the use of double underscore anywhere is reserved, period.

Comment: @KillzoneKid -- that quote does "suggest" anything, and it's not at all ambiguous. It **says** that names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved. That's the rule, and that's the way it has always been. Cfront used double underscores in the names that it generated.

Comment: @PeteBecker I found the source of the ambiguity "Use of two sequential underscore characters ( __ ) at the beginning of an identifier, or a single leading underscore followed by a capital letter, is reserved for C++ implementations in all scopes" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/identifiers-cpp

Comment: @KillzoneKid that quote is not from the standard and therefore isn't normative. Microsoft is technically free to unreserve double underscore from other than beginning in their own implementation but it won't affect other implementations.

Comment: @user2079303 I realised that, however the section `Microsoft Specific` ends with `END Microsoft Specific` before that paragraph, implying that it is not specific to MS.

Comment: @Killzone it's probably a mistake by the author of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As (by definition) you can't create instances of abstract classes, a `std::vector<>` can't contain *instances* of abstract classes. You need to change your container to contain *pointers*. Then the pointer type can be a pointer to an abstract class.

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why I did not realised that. I changed it and now it compiles just fine.